# Magento2.4.5-p1 coupon with uses per coupon 1 and per customer with coupon not working

Tags: coupon, coupon-codes, promotions, magento2.4.5, magento2.4.5p1

1. Magento Version - 2.4.5-p1
2. Using FPC (full page cache enabled)

**Issue:** Create a coupon with uses per coupon as 1 and uses per customer as 1 also. Even both uses type set to 1 even after that we are able to apply coupon mutliple times and it shows success message.

**Current Result:** Applying same coupon with same customer is getting applied.

**Expected Result:** If uses per coupon and per customer set 1 than once order placed with coupon and again applying same coupon should give error.

**Other Queries:**

a. Is it same issue mentioned here https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/miscellaneous/coupon-code-used-more-than-once-adobe-commerce.html?lang=en

B. Is this issue exist and valid for 2.4.5-p1 also.

C. Is it related to Cron configuration options for group:consumers and if yes what time interval needs to set inside

[image]

**Steps to Reproduce:** Create a coupon like:
[image]
[image]

I am able to place 2 order with this coupon and with same customer.

Comment: Still issue on magento 2 https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23907 Can any one have solution ?